# Lowering latency to distant endpoint

Tags: vpn, ping, internet, latency

I need the lowest possible latency from Bulgaria to Korea.

From what I understand, as an individual there is not much I can do to choose which physical cable my internet traffic travels on across Eurasia (or through the ocean). This is the realm of ISPs.

In the past I used an "accelerator" VPN service, which lowered my round trip latency from 280ms to 180ms. Whatever route they were using is now unavailable. I notice the parent company of the service I used - NetEase does not own an ISP, so obviously you don't need to be one to solve this problem.

I have read the documentation of various AWS/G Cloud/Tencent VPS and networking services, hoping I can piggyback on their infrastructure to set up my own VPN, but it does not seem it will affect my latency.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: You omitted the most important piece of information: your SLA.  If you want a faster connection, it starts there. If you don't have that, there are other forums such as SuperUser. https://www.verizon.com/business/terms/us/products/internet/sla/

Answer (score 0):

1. For real-time data the only possible solution is to install your application stack in Korea, which seems pretty easy, if we're talking South one. :)
2. If your application stack is a typical HTTP one, another partial solution would be to use and CDN that can host static data in Korea; however, the real dynamic data will have the same latency. But most of the time this is quite enough to make users feel your stack is very responsive.

Answer (score 0):

> but it does not seem it will affect my latency.

Theoretically it can, in the same way that the "accelerator" VPN services do it. Even if you just set up a personal VPN server, it still means the traffic takes a different path (often ISPs have a semi-direct peering with Google) – and could be that the "new" path from your location to GCP, through the internal GCP backbone, and out to the final destination will be better than what your ISP offers for general traffic. (But it also could be worse. Get a test server, `ping` it from your location, ping your destination from the server itself, compare the total.)

> NetEase does not own an ISP, so obviously you don't need to be one to solve this problem.

One doesn't *need* to be an "ISP" in the strict sense of Providing Internet Service to customers; literally any organization can have its own AS number and arrange its own connections with actual ISPs and other networks, if it has a need. (Including even hobbyist 1-person "organizations".) Pretty much every larger server-hosting company will have a dedicated ASN and often more than one upstream connection, just like an ISP would.